# Function to get rolling average with lowest 2 values eliminated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, window-functions

This is my sample data with the current_Rating column my desired output.

```
Date         Name    Subject         Importance    Location     Time      Rating  Current_rating
12/08/2020   David   Work            1             London       -         -       4
1/08/2020    David   Work            3             London       23.50     4       3.66
2/10/2019    David   Emails          3             New York     18.20     3       4.33
2/08/2019    David   Emails          3             Paris        18.58     4       4
11/07/2019   David   Work            1             London       -         3       4
1/06/2019    David   Work            3             London       23.50     4       4
2/04/2019    David   Emails          3             New York     18.20     3       5
2/03/2019    David   Emails          3             Paris        18.58     5       -
12/08/2020   George  Updates         2             New York     -         -       2
1/08/2019    George  New Appointments5             London       55.10     2       -
```

I need to use a function to get values in the current_Rating column.The current_Rating gets the previous 5 results from the rating column for each name, then eliminates the lowest 2 results, then gets the average for the remaining 3. Also some names may not have 5 results, so I will just need to get the average of the results if 3 or below, if 4 results I will need to eliminate the lowest value and average the remaining 3. Also to get the right 5 previous results it will need to be sorted by date. Is this possible? Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a custom [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html).

Comment: Do you need only average number of first 3 values? Do you need function to get this result? Do you need average result of only one name or all? There are so many unclear points.

Comment: @Abdusoli Sorry if I was unclear. It needs to be the average of the highest 3 numbers, from the past 5 results.  It needs to be a function to get every entry this rolling average. If no previous meeting for the name then it will return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a pain!  I think the simplest method might be to use arrays and then `unnest()` and aggregate:

```
select t.*, r.current_rating
from (select t.*,
             array_agg(rating) over (partition by name order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as rating_5
      from t
     ) t cross join lateral
     (select avg(r) as current_rating
      from (select u.*
            from unnest(t.rating_5) with ordinality u(r, n)
            where r is not null
            order by r desc desc
            limit 3
           ) r
     ) r
```

Comment: Thanks for your time again Gordon. It almost works perfectly, we're close. This creates 3 columns, one is rating_5 with the latest 5 ratings in it which works as intended, then it creates 2 identical current_rating columns. Problem with it is  it gets the average of the last 5, instead of eliminating the lowest 2 values.

Comment: @undecided000 . . . Duh.  The innermost subquery should have `limit 3` (which it now has).  That is the point of the `order by`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but the limit 3 has now meant it only calculates the average of the last 3 values?

Comment: @undecided000 . . . I fixed the order by.  It is the three highest values now.

Comment: @undecided000 . . . You ask interesting questions.